# Gunshot SFX Design: Should I use the actual model gun sound?

Tags: design, sfx, gun

This may be related to the question I asked before. Is it necessary to use the actual gunshot SFX for that model of gun in movies? I mean I understand that we should add something for gunshot SFX to make it more dramatic. But SFX design is an creative process. I saw many Hollywood Blockbusters that I suspected they were not using the same gunshot SFX with the same model of guns shown on screen. What are the reasons and trending behind this?
(But I agreed that the sound of AK 47 can't be replaced!)

Answer (score 1):

I think firstly, Ah Keh, it depends on how well you want your work to be respected and appreciated (and how much the job pays!) but also, it depends on what the director wants.

But these days (and maybe now I'm a *bit* older), people do seem to differentiate between the AK47 and the M16, for example. But then the AK *does* have a very distinctive sound, maybe because they are cheap, and everywhere. Unfortunately, there are places in the world where every home has an AK47 hanging on the wall, just in case.

But I think people can differentiate more because of things like video games and Youtube. Modern combat video games use very realistic gun model SFX. And we see videos all the time on the news or on youtube of real people shooting real guns. So we are more in touch with reality in this case. More respectable movies and series try to capture this with equally realistic SFX.

One thing I hate, Personally, is when Triple X, or some other exaggerated hero pulls out a Glock, and this horrendous, overpowering BOOM blasts from the gun, like a nuclear blast just went off. It makes me feel patronized.

You should simply use your judgment on this anyway, if it's easy for you to get SFX from a similar model that is used, then by all means, do it. I like the modern, realistic sound of a gritty, snappy gunshot. The raw, slightly enhanced sound seems to be the current trend.

I hope this helps.